# Distinct Count SQL

Tags: sql, distinct

I tried searching this forum for an answer but could not find one that fit mine dilemma exactly.

I have a list of claims that can be in different statuses.  I want a distinct count of claims where the status is open. The example below details three columns; Claim, ClaimLine, and Status

```
Claim | ClaimLine | Status
------+-----------+--------
    1 |         1 | Open
    1 |         2 | Open
    1 |         3 | Open
    2 |         1 | Enroute
    2 |         2 | Enroute
    3 |         1 | Closed
    4 |         1 | Open
    5 |         1 | Open
    5 |         2 | Open
    5 |         3 | Open
```

Desired Output:

```
Open
3
```

Comment: select Status,count(distinct Claim) from your_table where Status='Open' group by Status

Comment: @inquisitive_mind -- you should make that an answer instead of a comment

Comment: @RossPresser - yes, I should have.There goes my 60 points haha :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it:

Sample Data:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (Claim int , Claim_Line int , Status VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO #temp
VALUES
(1 ,1 ,'Open'), 
(1 ,2 ,'Open'), 
(1 ,3 ,'Open'), 
(2 ,1 ,'En-route'), 
(2 ,2 ,'En-route'), 
(3 ,1 ,'Closed'),
(4 ,1 ,'Open'), 
(5 ,1 ,'Open'), 
(5 ,2 ,'Open'), 
(5 ,3 ,'Open')
```

Query:

```
SELECT  Status, COUNT(DISTINCT Claim) FROM #temp 
WHERE Status = 'Open'
GROUP BY Status
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: @JamieD77 thanks for the comment. I have updated the solution.

Answer (score 1):

This way you don't have to group, a simplified version below this example :

```
select count(distinct claim),'Open' from (
select 1 as Claim, 1 as Claim_Line, 'Open' as Status 
union all 
select 1, 2, 'Open'
union all
select 1, 3, 'Open' 
union all 
select 2, 1, 'En-route' 
union all 
select 2, 2, 'En-route' 
union all 
select 3, 1, 'Closed' 
union all 
select 4, 1, 'Open' 
union all 
select 5, 1, 'Open'
union all 
select 5, 2, 'Open' 
union all 
select 5, 3, 'Open')sunquery  where status = 'Open'
```

simplified version:

```
select count(distinct claim),'Open' from Claims
where status = 'Open'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [COUNT()](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp) function with DISTINCT parameter.

So it will be something like that:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Status) FROM 
  (SELECT * FROM table_name
   GROUP BY Claim)
WHERE Status = 'Open'
GROUP BY Status
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
SELECT Status, COUNT(1) as Count FROM Claim 
WHERE Status = 'Open' GROUP BY Status
```

Comment: i like this answer since you already know the status should be Open but it doesn't produce the desired output.

Comment: @montelof, now it shows status as well as count. If you need all the status just remove the where clause.

Comment: I just got the idea of use the text in the select without having to group by that field and posted my own answer :)